# Combobox is it open or not!

Tags: actionscript-3, combobox, drop-down-menu

I have a problem to determinate if my combobox is open or not.
I've seen the same topic but that solution : `if(combobox.dropdown != null && combobx.dropdown.visible)` doesn't work for me. It is always true. I can't find any component who is responsible for this such a simple operation.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ComboBoxes have 2 events that are thrown regarding the open/closing action. If you bind to those events with an `addEventListener` you can easily track its state:

```
close    Dispatched when the drop-down list is dismissed for any reason.    ComboBox
open     Dispatched when the user clicks the drop-down button to display the drop-down list.    ComboBox
```

API Reference:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/ComboBox.html

Comment: Thanks Ben, I spent so much time looking for an attribute responsible for opening and forgot about events!  It works for me.
Thanks again

Comment: Hi Alexander. When someone has posted a correct answer, you typically accept the answer by clicking the checkmark and/or give an upvote (by clicking the up arrow next to the answer). I realize you're new to using the site so just wanted to say that and also welcome to stackoverflow.